# Set Python Flask Secret Key in Windows

Tags: python, windows, flask

I am working on a Python Flask Web App in Windows, and I cannot set my secret key as an environment variable.  I have set it through PowerShell and Windows GUI.  I have also tried using Git Bash to set it.  I can successfully set and return the environment variable in all instances.

In my Flask config, I have:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("MY_SECRET_KEY", "")
```

I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: the session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.
```

If I hard code the secret key, it works fine.  I understand there might be the question of *why* I want to set the secret key as an environment variable, and my current assumption is I want to know what it is, and I don't want it in the code.

I'm open to any thoughts and suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: you can definitely access environmental variables in Windows Python... as such I assume that you are not setting the enviromental variable correctly prior to launchin your script

Comment: Could you be more specific about setting the environment variable?  I went directly into the windows advanced settings and set both a User and System variable, and it still didn't work.

Comment: how are you running your script? open a terminal and run python and `print os.environ` (ofc after you `import os`

Comment: you should use `os.environ["MY_SECRET_KEY"]` so that you **will fail surely and early** if the variable is not set.

Comment: `os.environ["MY_SECRET_KEY"] ` was the solution.  Now my environment variable is recognized.

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\py_exp>set MY_VAR=123

C:\py_exp>echo %MY_VAR%
123

C:\py_exp>python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print os.environ["MY_VAR"]
123
```

not much of an answer but best I can do for you given the question